# Byte vs boolean for OrderBy

Tags: linq, sorting, boolean, byte, ienumerable

Is there any performance benefit to using a byte over a bool in ordering?

For example, given some code:

```
var foo = items.OrderByDescending(item => item.SomeProperty);
```

The existing code to get the value of SomeProperty is:

```
public byte SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (a == b)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I wanted to refactor this to:

```
public bool SomeProperty
{
    get 
    {
        a == b
    }
}
```

I was told the first is more efficient. Is this true? Are there any downsides to using a bool over a byte?

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency will hardly be in the processing efficiency. It will be more in efficiency of development code: is the code easy to understand? easy to reuse for similar items? easy to change if the internal structure changes without changing the interface? easy to test?

When designing a property your first question should be: what does my property stand for? What does it mean? Does it have an identifier and type that users will expect, or will they have to look it up in the documentation because they have no idea what it means?

For instance, if you have a class that represents something persistable, like a file, and you invent a property, which one will be easier to understand:

```
class Persistable
{
    public int IsPersisted {get;}
    public bool IsPersisted {get;}
    ...
```

Which one will readers immediately know what it means?

So for now your idea about persisted can have two values meaning "not persisted yet" and "persisted". A boolean will be enough. But if you foresee that in the near future the idea about persistence will change, for instance, the persistable can be "not persisted yet" "persisted" "changed after it has been persisted" "deleted". If you foresee that, you have to decide whether it is best to return a bool. Maybe your should return an enum:

```
public PersistencyState State {get;}
```

**Conclusion** Design the identifiers and types of your properties and methods such that the learning curve for your users is low, and that foreseeable changes don't have a great impact. Make sure that the properties are easy to test and maintain. In rare occasions portability is an issue.

Those items have bigger influence on your efficiency than the two code changes.

**Back to your question**

If you think about what `SomeProperty` represents, and you think: it represents the equality of a and b, then you should use:

public bool EqualAB => a == b

If your question is about whether you should use "get" or =>, the first one will call something sub-routine like, while the 2nd method will insert the code. If the part after the => is fairly big, and you use it on hundreds of locations, then your code will become bigger.

But then again: if your get is really big, should you make it a property?

```
public string ElderName
{
    get
    {
        myDataBase.Open()
        var allCustomers = myDataBase.FetchAllCustomers().ToList();
        var eldestCustomer = this.FindEldestCustomer(allCustomers);
        return eldestCustomer.Name;
    }
}
```

Well this will have a fair impact on code size if you use the => notation on 1000 locations. But honestly, designers that put this in a property instead of a method don't deserve efficient code.

Finally, I asked here in stackoverflow whether there is a difference:

```
string Name {get => this.name;}
string Name => this.name;
```

The answer was that it translated into the same assembly code

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! My question was mostly about bool vs byte, not about "get" vs =>. I edited the question to make this clearer.